# Why is my Django view being hit twice with every page view?

Tags: django, django-views

I can't seem to find the problem for the life of me. Very simply, I have a database object that I'm pulling from the database, incrementing it's "views" by one, and saving. My view display's the incremented value, but then my logs show that the value is incremented AGAIN.

```
g=Game.objects.filter(slug=slug).distinct()[0]
g.views += 1
g.save()
```

Here's my logs:

```
[Fri Oct 29 15:15:49 2010] [error] DEBUG:root:Updating plays
[Fri Oct 29 15:15:49 2010] [error] DEBUG:root:plays: 40
[Fri Oct 29 15:15:50 2010] [error] DEBUG:root:Updating plays
[Fri Oct 29 15:15:50 2010] [error] DEBUG:root:plays: 41
```

My view shows that it has 40 hits. This causes that my view increments by 2 every time I refresh:

```
[Fri Oct 29 15:20:19 2010] [error] DEBUG:root:Updating plays 
[Fri Oct 29 15:20:19 2010] [error] DEBUG:root:plays: 42
[Fri Oct 29 15:20:19 2010] [error] DEBUG:root:Updating plays
[Fri Oct 29 15:20:19 2010] [error] DEBUG:root:plays: 43
```

Any hints as to what this could be?

EDIT:

Here's my view. I simplified it to the core elements (and it still behaves oddly).

```
def game(request, slug=None):

    g=Game.objects.filter(slug=slug)[0]

    if g:
        comments=GameComment.objects.filter(item=g, parent__isnull=True)
        g.plays+=1
        g.save()
    else:
        comments=None

    return render_to_response('goto/goto_game.html', {'g': g, 'comments':comments, 'cCount':len(comments) if comments else 0, 'newCCount':0}, request=request)
```

Comment: whats your def logic in views.py? and how are you extending your template? - add these to you question please?

Comment: As a side note, if you are using SlugField for your slug, it will bu default have a unique constraint, so filtering and then calling distinct can be reduced to a simple get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AH! Turns out it was a missing url and ajax issue. It wasn't the favicon, as that only hits the root, and not my specific view.

The problem came when I had an AJAX command like this:

```
$.post('{{url("_submitcomment")}}', data, function(data) { ...
```

and that 'url' could not reverse '_submitcomment' so returned an empty string. Calling

```
$.post('');
```

will hit your current URL and try to fetch everything!

(I'm using Jinja2, btw, so the url command probably looks different from them traditional Django template system.)

Thanks for the help and the tips!

Comment: this will also happen if your "onsubmit" function does not return "false". also, instead of printing JS code from the template you could just print the data - like the url. for example <script ..>var data = data || {}; data.url = '{% url _submitcomment %}';</script> and the rest of your js can go to external file.

Comment: Sweet, I'll have to give that a try! Unfortunately, I have another problem with another part of the code. My "hit counter" shows 24 hits, while google analytics shows 500+. Oh well, that's worth another question on its own. :P

Answer (score 3):

In my case, each view was called twice, because my base template contained incorrect icon link in the `<head>` tag. It might look like this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="#">
```

So, after the page is loaded the browser sends a request to the current page again, which causes the second view call.

Remove the wrong `<link>` tag, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify the second request is not for "/favicon.ico" ?