# Django calling view method twice

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This is my `url.py` code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test/', views.test, name='test'),
]
```

This is my `views.py` code:

```
def test(request):

    print  ("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")


    return render(request, 'my_app/index_test.html')
```

This is my output from console

```
Django version 1.10.6, using settings 'some_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 26814
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/css/normalize.css HTTP/1.1" 200 8053
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 102897
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 21979
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/css/animate.css HTTP/1.1" 200 63414
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/css/gg_preloading.css HTTP/1.1" 200 3816
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/css/prettyPhoto.css HTTP/1.1" 200 19888
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 23649
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 93107
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 200 58327
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/js/waypoints.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 8044
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/js/jquery.scrollto.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2434
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/js/jquery.localscroll.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1560
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/js/scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5183
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/js/less.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 143621
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/img/empty_1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 15358
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/img/empty_2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 15411
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_Banner-6.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 47285
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/pic/hotlog_counter.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1700
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_Banner-5.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 31588
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_Banner-1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 33355
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_Banner-2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 29322
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_Banner-3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 24960
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:41] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_Banner-4.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 23886
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:42] "GET /static/less/style.less HTTP/1.1" 200 4607
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:42] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_%D0%98%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-5.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 129141
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:42] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_%D0%98%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-6.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 95125
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:42] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_%D0%98%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-7.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 101621
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:42] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_%D0%98%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-4.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 110054
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /static/img/fairy_logo_large.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5794
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /static/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 65452
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /static/img/fairy_bckgrnd.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 226213
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /static/img/sprite_social_element.png HTTP/1.1" 200 11187
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /static/img/lang_picto.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6577
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /static/img/bullet.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2828
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /test/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26814
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /static/img/fairies_features.png HTTP/1.1" 200 482983
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /static/img/best.png HTTP/1.1" 200 72272
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_%D0%98%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-11.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 262491
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_%D0%98%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-8.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 255375
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /static/img/video.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2672
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_%D0%98%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-9.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 329229
[03/Apr/2017 01:24:43] "GET /static/pic/%D0%9D%D0%91_%D0%98%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-10.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 160719
```

After I reload my page or just go to it,
you can see it prints `++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++` two times.

What do I do??

Comment: I noticed that you're loading "scripts.js" file in there. Is it doing anything like setting the window.location? Have you had a read through the solutions put forward [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056024/why-is-my-django-view-being-hit-twice-with-every-page-view) to see if anything in there is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

From the log output, we can see that the second call to your view function is triggered by the URL `/test/images/favicon.ico`. You probably have a line like this in your template:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
```

Note that there's no slash before `images`, which means that the URL will be treated as relative to the current page URL, `/test/`. You should change this line to point to the correct location of your favicon (probably something like `/static/img/favicon.ico`), or delete it completely if you don't have one.

The URL `/test/images/favicon.ico` is triggering your view function because
the pattern `r'^test/'` matches all URLs beginning with `/test/`. If you want it to *only* match the specific URL `/test/`, the line should be:

```
url(r'^test/$', views.test, name='test'),
```